# Reshape data frame, by adding new columns with 0 values

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem with creating training and testing split on data frame.
After pivoting and grouping my full DF has shape of (1295, 6835).

The two subsets of this data made the same way from same file split into two, containing features(training data) and response variables(data I want to predict).

they have a shape features (1287,6631) and response (1068, 1977).

Here is obvious dimensions miss-match, both features and response should have same 6835 as original data.

How to pad these sequences with zeros keeping original size and column names, so I could validate this?

```
import numpy as np
allData = pd.read_csv('path_tocsv.csv')
months = pd.read_csv('path_to_train_months.csv')
march = pd.read_csv('path_to_predictmonth.csv')
```

this gives shapes:
next pivoting the data:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(allData, values='Qty', columns='Item', index=['Subinventory Code'], fill_value=0.0)
df[df < 0 ] = 0
df1 = pd.pivot_table(months, values='Qty', columns='Item', index=['Subinventory Code'], fill_value=0.0)
df1[df1 < 0 ] = 0
df2 = pd.pivot_table(march, values='Qty', columns='Item', index=['Subinventory Code'], fill_value=0.0)
df2[df2 < 0 ] = 0
```

Data has shape:
df (1295, 6835)
df1 (1287,6631)
df2 (1068,1977)
Creating dictionary containing probabilities for each row in df's

```
def getProbas(df, cols, train=True):
probasDict = dict()
if train == True:
    for y,z in df.iterrows():
        locSum = z.sum()
        newZ = pd.Series([v/locSum for v in z])
        probasDict[y] = newZ
else:
    for y,z in df.iterrows():
        newZ = pd.Series([v for v in z])
        probasDict[y] = newZ

return probasDict

cols = list(df.columns)
fullDict = getProbas(df, cols, train=True)
trainDict = getProbas(df1, cols, train=True)
testDicts = getProbas(df2, cols, train=False)
```

Here I am creating data frames from dicts.

```
dfAll = pd.DataFrame.from_items(fullDict.items(), orient = 'index', columns = cols)
    dfTrain = pd.DataFrame.from_items(trainDict.items(), orient = 'index', columns = list(df1.columns))
    dfTest = pd.DataFrame.from_items(testDict.items(), orient = 'index', columns = list(df2.columns))
```

After this shapes are the same as previously:
dfAll (1295, 6835)
dfTrain (1287,6631)
dfTest (1068,1977)

There is less observation for month that I would like to predict, but would like to be able to have flexible model, for all observations.

So the goal would be to have dfTrain, and dfTest in shapes (x, 6835)

Does this make sense?

Comment: You should post the code you use to split the data, and if possible a small example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Good point apologies for not including this sooner.